# embed a texture to mesh

Tags: texture-baking

sorry if the title is wrong but basically i got a cube mesh, on one of the faces is a texture with a black x on it, is there a way to extrude the x on the face so i can see it without the texture. (the x doesnt have to be black on the face, i just has to "pop out" )

i am a newb so some easy tutorials could help , or some key words i can search.

Comment: Yes, you need to subdivide the mesh and use your texture as a displacement map. Normally in a displacement texture; White = fully displaced, black = no displacement. But you should be able to flip the displacement direction in the modifier without changing the texture.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44758/emboss-text-onto-curved-surface https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55184/remove-inset-area-fill-embossed-text https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41050/boolean-and-texts/